# data frame is not stacked vertically when saved

Tags: python, pandas, csv

data1.dat

```
   1 ASN C  7.042   9.118  0.000 1 1 1 1  1  0
   2 LEU H  5.781   5.488  7.470 0 0 0 0  1  0
   3 THR H  5.399   5.166  6.452 0 0 0 0  0  0
   4 GLU H  5.373   4.852  6.069 0 0 0 0  1  0
   5 LEU H  5.423   5.164  6.197 0 0 0 0  2  0
   6 LYS H  5.247   4.943  6.434 0 0 0 0  1  0
   7 ASN C  5.485   8.103  8.264 0 0 0 0  1  0
   8 THR C  6.675   9.152  9.047 0 0 0 0  1  0
   9 PRO C  6.372   8.536 11.954 0 0 0 0  0  0
  10 VAL H  5.669   5.433  6.703 0 0 0 0  0  0
  11 SER H  5.304   4.924  6.407 0 0 0 0  0  0
  12 GLU H  5.461   5.007  6.088 0 0 0 0  1  0
  13 LEU H  5.265   5.057  6.410 0 0 0 0  3  0
  14 ILE H  5.379   5.026  6.206 0 0 0 0  1  0
  15 THR H  5.525   5.154  6.000 0 0 0 0  1  0
  16 LEU H  5.403   5.173  6.102 0 0 0 0  1  0
  17 GLY H  5.588   5.279  6.195 0 0 0 0  1  0
  18 GLU H  5.381   5.238  6.675 0 0 0 0  1  0
  19 ASN H  5.298   5.287  6.668 0 0 0 0  1  0
  20 MSE H  5.704   7.411  4.926 0 0 0 0  1  0
```

data2.dat

```
  21 GLY C  5.978   9.254  9.454 0 0 0 0  1  0
  22 LEU C  6.778  10.534 12.640 0 0 1 2  2  0
  23 GLU C  7.187   7.217 10.728 0 0 0 0  2  0
  24 ASN C  5.392   8.296 10.702 0 0 0 0  0  0
  25 LEU C  5.657   6.064  9.609 0 0 0 1  3  0
  26 ALA C  5.446   5.528  7.503 0 0 0 0  2  0
  27 ARG C  5.656   8.071  8.419 0 0 0 0  0  0
  28 MSE C  6.890   9.157  8.728 0 0 0 0  1  0
  29 ARG C  6.330   7.993 11.562 0 0 0 0  0  0
  30 LYS H  5.428   5.207  5.897 0 0 0 0  1  0
  31 GLN H  5.402   5.046  6.349 0 0 0 0  1  0
  32 ASP H  5.426   5.093  6.226 0 0 0 1  1  0
  33 ILE H  5.361   5.004  6.194 0 0 0 0  6  0
  34 ILE H  5.443   5.150  6.190 0 0 0 0  5  0
  35 PHE H  5.403   5.181  6.293 0 0 0 0  1  0
  36 ALA H  5.533   5.357  6.193 0 0 0 0  3  0
  37 ILE H  5.634   5.167  6.025 0 0 0 1  5  0
  38 LEU H  5.402   5.121  6.104 0 0 0 0  3  0
  39 LYS H  5.470   5.092  6.101 0 0 0 0  1  0
  40 GLN H  5.491   5.210  6.054 0 0 0 0  2  0
```

```
import os
import pandas as pd
from src.utils.get_root_dir import get_root_directory

def save_dataframe_to_ascii(df, filepath):
    df.to_csv(filepath, sep=',', index=False)

def getDataFrame(dataDirectoryPathString: str) -> pd.DataFrame:
    dataframes = []
    for filename in os.listdir(dataDirectoryPathString):
        if filename.endswith('.dat'):
            filepath = os.path.join(dataDirectoryPathString, filename)
            df = pd.read_csv(filepath, sep='\t')
            dataframes.append(df)
    concatenated_df = pd.concat(dataframes, ignore_index=True)
    return concatenated_df


if __name__ == "__main__":
    dataFrame = getDataFrame(get_root_directory() + "/data/")
    save_dataframe_to_ascii(dataFrame, get_root_directory() + "/save/save.txt")
```

Output:

```
   1 ASN C  7.042   9.118  0.000 1 1 1 1  1  0,  21 GLY C  5.978   9.254  9.454 0 0 0 0  1  0
   2 LEU H  5.781   5.488  7.470 0 0 0 0  1  0,
   3 THR H  5.399   5.166  6.452 0 0 0 0  0  0,
   4 GLU H  5.373   4.852  6.069 0 0 0 0  1  0,
   5 LEU H  5.423   5.164  6.197 0 0 0 0  2  0,
   6 LYS H  5.247   4.943  6.434 0 0 0 0  1  0,
   7 ASN C  5.485   8.103  8.264 0 0 0 0  1  0,
   8 THR C  6.675   9.152  9.047 0 0 0 0  1  0,
   9 PRO C  6.372   8.536 11.954 0 0 0 0  0  0,
  10 VAL H  5.669   5.433  6.703 0 0 0 0  0  0,
  11 SER H  5.304   4.924  6.407 0 0 0 0  0  0,
  12 GLU H  5.461   5.007  6.088 0 0 0 0  1  0,
  13 LEU H  5.265   5.057  6.410 0 0 0 0  3  0,
  14 ILE H  5.379   5.026  6.206 0 0 0 0  1  0,
  15 THR H  5.525   5.154  6.000 0 0 0 0  1  0,
  16 LEU H  5.403   5.173  6.102 0 0 0 0  1  0,
  17 GLY H  5.588   5.279  6.195 0 0 0 0  1  0,
  18 GLU H  5.381   5.238  6.675 0 0 0 0  1  0,
  19 ASN H  5.298   5.287  6.668 0 0 0 0  1  0,
  20 MSE H  5.704   7.411  4.926 0 0 0 0  1  0,
,  22 LEU C  6.778  10.534 12.640 0 0 1 2  2  0
,  23 GLU C  7.187   7.217 10.728 0 0 0 0  2  0
,  24 ASN C  5.392   8.296 10.702 0 0 0 0  0  0
,  25 LEU C  5.657   6.064  9.609 0 0 0 1  3  0
,  26 ALA C  5.446   5.528  7.503 0 0 0 0  2  0
,  27 ARG C  5.656   8.071  8.419 0 0 0 0  0  0
,  28 MSE C  6.890   9.157  8.728 0 0 0 0  1  0
,  29 ARG C  6.330   7.993 11.562 0 0 0 0  0  0
,  30 LYS H  5.428   5.207  5.897 0 0 0 0  1  0
,  31 GLN H  5.402   5.046  6.349 0 0 0 0  1  0
,  32 ASP H  5.426   5.093  6.226 0 0 0 1  1  0
,  33 ILE H  5.361   5.004  6.194 0 0 0 0  6  0
,  34 ILE H  5.443   5.150  6.190 0 0 0 0  5  0
,  35 PHE H  5.403   5.181  6.293 0 0 0 0  1  0
,  36 ALA H  5.533   5.357  6.193 0 0 0 0  3  0
,  37 ILE H  5.634   5.167  6.025 0 0 0 1  5  0
,  38 LEU H  5.402   5.121  6.104 0 0 0 0  3  0
,  39 LYS H  5.470   5.092  6.101 0 0 0 0  1  0
,  40 GLN H  5.491   5.210  6.054 0 0 0 0  2  0
```

The rows should have been stacked vertically.

Why is the output broken?

How can I fix it?

Comment: The rows *are* stacked vertically; it's the input that's broken. Please make a [mre]. For specifics, see [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](/q/20109391/4518341). For more tips, like how to write a good title, check out [ask].

Comment: @wjandrea, Input is 100% ok.

Comment: Sorry, I should clarify: either the input or how you're processing it is wrong. Like maybe the input files aren't actually tab-separated.

Comment: @wjandrea, Check the edit

Comment: Yup, those are spaces. BTW, Stack Overflow renders tabs to 4 spaces, so I had to check the source to confirm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need to use Pandas, and I don't see you using it for anything other than concatenating (so far), I recommend using Python's csv module to stack CSV-like files—it'll be faster than Pandas and use next to zero memory:

```py
import csv

TAB = "\t"

# Get files first, using maybe just use `glob.glob(get_root_directory()+'/data/*.dat')`
dat_files = ["input1.dat", "input2.dat"]

with open("output.dat", "w", newline="", encoding="utf-8") as f_out:
    writer = csv.writer(f_out, delimiter=TAB)

    for dat_file in dat_files:
        with open(dat_file, newline="", encoding="utf-8") as f_in:
            reader = csv.reader(f_in, delimiter=TAB)

            writer.writerows(reader)
```

The `reader` variable is an iterator over all the rows in the file it was created with. Calling `writer.writerows(reader)` will cause every row in the reader to be iterated and handed directly to the writer for writing.  This approach also uses almost no memory as the row is just passing from input directly to output.

I also show getting the files first to avoid extra levels of indentation/complexity.

With the sample files you shared (and converting any number of spaces to a TAB), my output.dat looks like:

```
1   ASN C   7.042   9.118   0.000   1   1   1   1   1   0
2   LEU H   5.781   5.488   7.470   0   0   0   0   1   0
3   THR H   5.399   5.166   6.452   0   0   0   0   0   0
...
38  LEU H   5.402   5.121   6.104   0   0   0   0   3   0
39  LYS H   5.470   5.092   6.101   0   0   0   0   1   0
40  GLN H   5.491   5.210   6.054   0   0   0   0   2   0
```